# OpenERP/Odoo: fields.datetime.now() show the date of the latest restart

Tags: python, datetime, odoo

I have a field datetime. This field should have by default the datetime of "now", the current time.

However, the default date is the time of **the lastest restart**.

Please find below my code:

```
'date_action': fields.datetime('Date current action', required=False, readonly=False, select=True),

_defaults = {
    'date_action': fields.datetime.now(),
```

Comment: Can you give us some examples? I don't see a mistake in your code snippet

Comment: For exemple if I restart my ERP today at 16:36:30 , the default date will be always 30/08/2016 16:36:30. So tomorrow the default date will still be  30/08/2016 16:36:30 instead of the new current time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the default value of `date_action` as the value returned by `fields.datetime.now()`, that is executed when odoo server is started.

You should set the default value as the call to the method:

```
'date_action': fields.datetime.now,
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use `lambda`
For example in Odoo 8 :

```
date_action = fields.Datetime(string="Date current action",  default=lambda *a: datetime.now())
```