# Django: Form default date different on production server

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a `AddRecordTimeFrame` form.

```py
class AddRecordTimeFrame(forms.ModelForm, OverviewAddTimeframeMixin):
    start_date = forms.ChoiceField(label='Start Date:',widget=forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width:140px'}),choices=get_datetime_choices('date'),initial=datetime.date.today())
    start_time = TimeFieldHHSS(widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={'style': 'width:80px;height:23px'}))

    class Meta:
        model = RecordModel
        fields = ('test_cell','start_date','start_time',)
        labels = RecordModel.RECORD_NAMING_CONV
```

The initial value being `datetime.date.today()`, returns correctly on my Development server but does not on Production server. But in fact returns the date in which I last restart the server as the initial value (*Which was Oct 13 2020*).

**What i've tried**

So upon a bit of research ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39232076/11475846)). I found that when the server is restarted `datetime.datetime.today()` is executed but what actually needs to be passed into the initial keyword argument is just the function.

So I replace all instances of

`datetime.datetime.today() --> datetime.datetime.today`

This did not make a difference.

**Development Version**

[image]

**Production Version**

[image]

I would like to determine the cause of this behavior and how to rectify the issue to allow the current datetime to show as default in the production server.

**Software**

- Both use same version of source code and requirements versions(Python, Django etc.)
- Both MariaDB

***Development***

- Windows 7

***Production***

- Linux (Debian)
- NginX
- Gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

You should set `TIME_ZONE` in the `settings.py` file.